# Use the @task decorator or set the 'tasks' attribute of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)

Tags: django-rest-framework, locust

My wish is to run the locust file separately but here coming issues. In my `locustio` folder have multiple files named are, `base.py`, `locust_test_adio.py`, and `locust_test_project.py`.

When I run this command **(** `locust -f common/locustio/locust_test_adio.py` **)** the get called `locust_test_adio.py` is working fine.
But at the same time when I run this **(** `locust -f common/locustio/locust_test_project.py` **)** for triggering the`locust_test_project.py` file thrown an error is,

```
Exception: No tasks defined on BaseLocustLoadTest. Use the @task decorator or set the 'tasks' attribute of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
```

**Can you please tell me where is the problem here? I tried different ways but didn't find the right solution.**

***base.py:***

```
from locust import HttpUser, between

class BaseLocustLoadTest(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2)

    def on_start(self):
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            "api/v1/token", json={"email": "mossaddak@gmail.com", "password": "1234"}
        )
        self.access_token = response.json()["access"]
        self.headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {self.access_token}"}

    def request_with_auth(self, method, path, **kwargs):
        return self.client.request(method, path, headers=self.headers, **kwargs)
```

***locust_test_adio.py:***

```
from locust import task
from base import BaseLocustLoadTest


class AdApiLocustLoadTest(BaseLocustLoadTest):
    # All tasks related to ads organization
    @task
    def list_ads_organization(self):
        self.adio_organization_response = self.request_with_auth(
            "GET", "api/v1/ads/organizations"
        )
```

***locust_test_project.py:***

```
from locust import task
from base import BaseLocustLoadTest


class ProjectApiLocustLoadTest(BaseLocustLoadTest):
    @task
    def get_project_list(self):
        self.request_with_auth("GET", "api/v1/we/projects")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `abstract` property of BaseLocustLoadTest class as abstract to True:

```
class BaseLocustLoadTest(HttpUser):
    abstract = True
    ...
```

This will prevent Locust from attempting to instantiate and run it.

Comment: sorry it didn't work, any more way? please suggest me if have

Comment: You’re almost certainly doing something else weird if that didnt help. Is the error message really unchanged? you edited base.py, right?

Comment: sorry it worked, now I also want to run all file together. Is it possible?

Comment: Just import all the classes into one file and locust will pick them up!